# При попытке вызвать функцию из другого файла происходит ошибка invalid syntax

Tags: python

При попытке вызвать функцию из другого файла в питоне происходит ошибка SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Код в config файле:

```
token = ''

symbols_list = ['!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '?', '*', '(', ')', '{', '}', '~']

import string
import telegrambot as tg

passwords = 10
text = ''

use_english = 'да'; use_figures = 'нет'; use_symbols = 'да'

def generate():
    if config.use_english == 'да' and config.use_figures == 'да' and config.use_symbols == 'да':
        for i in range(passwords):
            password = ''
            
            for x in range(config.lenght):
                password += random.choice(random.choice([string.ascii_letters, string.digits, symbols_list])
            tg.give()
```

Скриншот:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А откуда у вас взялся config? И есть ли у него свойство lenght?

Comment: А ошибка, это разумеется нехватка закрывающей скобки на предыдущей строке

Comment: Спасибо, исправил просто код из главного файла вставил в этот config файл и получилось такое вот..)

Comment: В конфиге, вместо да/нет лучше использовать нормальные булевы True/False

Comment: Трейсбеки ошибок лучше тоже вставлять текстом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как уже в отметил [vp_arth](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176064/vp-arth) в [комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1206680/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-invalid-syntax#comment2107498_1206680), у вас в 19й строке не хватает закрывающей скобки.

```py
password += random.choice(random.choice([string.ascii_letters, string.digits, symbols_list])
                                                                                            ^
                                                                                      вот тут
```

В данной строке сперва открываются круглые скобки у внешнего `random.choice`, затем у внутреннего, а закрывающая круглая скобка всего одна.